# Получение статистики поиска

Tags: seo, c#

Подскажите, кто-нибудь. Как осуществить разбор и выдачи поисковых запросов (любого поисковика)? Т.е. нужно определить, что чаще вводят в поисковик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любого? У всех нормальных поисковиков (Google, Yandex, Bing, Yahoo, ...) есть API. В нем есть целая куча методов, в том числе и популярные поисковые запросы, и т.д. Отправляешь запрос на специальный Url, в ответ получаешь json / xml, что больше нравится, и парсишь штатными средствами .Net, или с помощью библиотек, рекомендую Json.Net.

Но для *любого* поисковика этот метод конечно не подойдет. Для vasya-pupkin-search.com, прийдется писать костыль, так или иначе.